# Hiding .html extension in links

Tags: html, hyperlink, hide

Say I have a link like this on public_html/index.html:

```
<a href="pictures/index.html">Link to picture</a>
```

Since the "link to picture" has its own folder and uses index.html, normally that extension would be hidden if I type in "www.mywebsite.com/pictures". But if I first go to "www.mywebsite.com", then click that link, it would display in the address bar as "www.mywebsite.com/pictures/index.html". How would I hide the "index.html" in links? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="pictures/">Link to picture</a> <---this simply opens the file directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a server?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `httpd.conf` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

And by default if you don't pass in a filename `index.html` gets rendered instead of the directory content

Comment: What exactly is httpd.conf? I use Hostgator, and they use Apache. I know there's a .htaccess but never heard of httpd.conf, don't think I even have that file.

Comment: You can also put that code snippet in your `.htaccess` file :)